# Downloaded pages in Chrome for Android

Tags: google-chrome

Where are downloaded webpages saved for offline view in chrome for android are stored in memory ( file manager ) ?

Comment: Not a programming or Chrome Apps question.

Comment: Sorry I thought the chrome-app means the chrome android app.